# Unprotecting VBA Editor Triggers Sub

Tags: excel, password-protection, vba

I password protected my VBA Editor with:

1. Tools > VBAProject Properties > Protection
2. Clicked "Lock project for viewing"
3. Added a password.

What I need to have happen is that when this password prompt is accepted, It needs to run a Sub I've already written.

The answer I'm looking for and can't find in the three books on my desk is:
Is this action a Workbook Event?  Or something else?  And what syntax can make this happen.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as i know, the editor protection password is not exposed to the vba object, so i dont think there is any event that can be triggered.

Comment: I've been researching this all day and am pretty sure you're right.  The only potential solution is to script the Editor protection yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Potential solution from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa165442(v=office.10).aspx

This won't work for for what I'm trying to do.  I wrote a script that asks for a key delivered weekly to authorized users via another program.  What I wanted is a Sub to run which deletes all of my sensitive data if the user enters an incorrect password while attempting to get to the code.

Looks like this is not possible in Excel VBA... I'll keep learning and searching for a way to do this.  If I do I will revisit this post.